# Can we get P value for each row in a contingency table?

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I have following data on 4 different organisms infecting 115 adults and 69 children:

[image]

Chi-square test can be applied to this table, but it will only show that there is non-uniformity somewhere in the table. I want to compare how each organism relates to adults vs children.

Since number of samples in adult and children groups are not equal, I have calculated column percent for each organism separately for adults and children. By visually comparing column percentages, it appears (as highlighted in yellow) that organism A has greater predilection for children while adults are more susceptible to organisms C and D. Frequency of finding organism B seems to be nearly equal in adults and children. However, which formal statistical test should I apply to confirm these impressions?

Edit:
As suggested by @Patrick in his answer, I analyzed with [proportion testing](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_chisquare.html) on each row as follows:

```
        Adult  Children  Adult%  Children%  Pvalues  Significant  SigBonferroni
A      25.000    40.000  21.739     57.971    0.000         True           True
B      10.000     8.000   8.696     11.594    0.522        False          False
C      50.000    12.000  43.478     17.391    0.000         True           True
D      30.000     9.000  26.087     13.043    0.036         True          False
Total 115.000    69.000 100.000    100.000  

Percentages are column percentages.
P values are obtained by proportion testing for each row.
Significant is True if P<0.05
SigBonferroni indicates significance after Bonferroni correction, 
   i.e. P<0.05/(Number of tests=4), i.e. P<0.012
```

Above clearly shows that organism A has greater predilection for children while C is commoner in adults.

Trying Tukey's HSD as suggested by @whuber in comments:

```
Chi2 result of the contingency table: 28.567227276904696, p-value: 2.7609207293182665e-06
Significance results:
('A', 'B'): p_value: 0.303028; corrected: 0.363634 (ns) reject: False
('A', 'C'): p_value: 0.000003; corrected: 0.000020 (****) reject: True
('A', 'D'): p_value: 0.000317; corrected: 0.000950 (***) reject: True
('B', 'C'): p_value: 0.063603; corrected: 0.127205 (ns) reject: False
('B', 'D'): p_value: 0.184287; corrected: 0.276430 (ns) reject: False
('C', 'D'): p_value: 0.843860; corrected: 0.843860 (ns) reject: False
```

Using Tukey's Post-hoc with transposed data:

```
Chi2 result of the contingency table: 28.567227276904696, p-value: 2.7609207293182665e-06
Significance results:
('Adult', 'Children'): p_value: 0.000003; corrected: 0.000003 (****) reject: True
```

However, this is not answering the question "Which organisms have greater predilection for adults vs children?"

Code for Tukey's HSD adapted from [here](https://neuhofmo.github.io/chi-square-and-post-hoc-in-python/).

Comment: Tukey's HSD looks like a good option.

Comment: Isn't Tukey's HSD for Anova? How can I use it for Chi-square contingency table?

Comment: Tukey's HSD will give the difference between organism A vs B, A vs C... etc while I want adult vs children for A, adult vs children for B... etc.

Comment: @whuber : I have added Tukey's HSD results in my question above.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a two-proportion z test for each row. The null hypothesis being that the two groups have equal proportions. This is nicely worked out here: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/9/9.4

After doing the test you need to correct for the multiple comparisons by using a Bonferroni Correction - dividing the cut-off p-value (typically 0.05) by the number of tests that you did (4 in your example). So you would check if the p-values are below 0.0125.